# Why RSOLVE doesn't work here?

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to use RSOLVE but it doesn't work on very simple examples.

My real problem is a little long to explain, but I tried to use RSOLVE on simple case to "test" it and understand how it works and I have problems.

```
In[22]:= RSolve[a[x + 1, y + 1] == x y a[x, y], a[x, y], {x, y}]

Out[22]= {{a[x, y] -> 
   Pochhammer[1, -1 + x] Pochhammer[1 - x + y, -1 + x] C[1][x - y]}}

In[23]:= RSolve[a[x, y] == 2* a[x, y], a[x, y], {x, y}]

Out[23]= RSolve[a[x, y] == 2 a[x, y], a[x, y], {x, y}]
```

In the first example it perfectly find the solution.

But in the thecond it doesn't : it should find a[x,y]=0.

Why isn't it working ?

Comment: `a[x, y] == 2 a[x, y]` is not a recurrence equation

Comment: Ah yeah you are right.... Thanks !

Comment: `Solve[a[x, y] == 2*a[x, y], a[x, y], {x, y}]`

Comment: Yeah sure, but this was just to understand why Rsolve didn't work, I figured out that only reccurence equation can be solved by it I didn't paid attention at first.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote in your 2nd example is not a partial recurrence equation but a functional difference equation. As I read the documentation for `RSolve`, it can only solve functional difference equations of one variable. So

```
 RSolve[a[n] == 2 a[n], a, n]
```

> `{{a -> Function[{n}, 0]}}`

can be solved, but not

```
RSolve[a[x, y] == 2 a[x, y], a, {x, y}]
```